# HTML5 for Firefox 46.0.1 Ubuntu 12.04.5 Lts

Tags: 12.04, firefox, html5

I am a new user (ie. please be detailed). I have this version of Firefox : 46.0.1 installed and recently learned how to install Flash Player with great difficulty. Now I realize I cannot watch via Amazon Instant Video. Allegedly, I need to install HTML5 codec.

First, is this even supported on 12.04.5 Lts? Secondly, please provide directions on how to install via bash terminal.

Regards,

Comment: Do you mean HTML5 H.264 support? [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/389439/37165) from older post might be what you are looking for. It seems to be valid for 12.04, 14.04 and 16.04.

Comment: Well, let me put it this way, I am trying to get an understanding of how to resolve future issues of missing software. So if it is H.264, I would like to know why and steps to a solution. Regards, for the link.

Comment: The link provided by clearkimura was specifically for youtube. I do not think this applies to my question.

Comment: [This help page on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201460940) has noted that Firefox 47 or newer is required. All supported releases of Ubuntu has Firefox 47 in [the repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=firefox&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). Try upgrade Firefox first.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply... I called Amazon and wrote to firefox, still with no avail. I have also tried installing Hal (you can look this up it is a way to install flashplayer and have it run even though flashplayer is not supported on 16.04) to no avail. There is also a suggestion to install something similar to silverlight... All in all the easiest way out is to install google chrome.

Comment: Given that you had tried similar to [this older post](http://askubuntu.com/q/362259/37165) but still failed, perhaps you could self-answer this. In your answer, note the version of Google Chrome that actually worked for you to this date. Even other users have varying experience between upgrades, according [this search result](http://askubuntu.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20amazon%20instant%20video) on Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

So keep in mind folks, amazon instant video worked on google chrome AFTER I tried installing 'Hal' + 'ubuntu-restricted-extras' + 'flash player' to get it to work on firefox. So after these three, I just used the graphical interface and downloaded directly from google's desktop site this version: 64 bit .deb (For Debian/Ubuntu).